# How to obtain the original mapping from the first fundamental form?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

Suppose I have a bounded surface with principle curvatures = $0$. I am given the first fundamental form $\mathbf{a}$ with entries $E, F, G$. I know that these entries are obtained by taking some mapping $\vec{m}(u,v)$ and dotting its various derivatives, eg. $E = \vec{m}_u \cdot \vec{m}_u$. Is it possible to work backwards from $\mathbf{a}$ to obtain a unique $\vec{m}$?

For example I could construct a system of equations based on these derivative components:

$$
m_{u1}(m_{u1}) + m_{u2}(m_{u2}) = E \\
m_{u1}(m_{v1}) + m_{u2}(m_{v2}) = F\\
m_{v1}(m_{v1}) + m_{v2}(m_{v2}) = G$$

Then if I had one extra equation I could solve for $m_{u1}, m_{v1}, m_{u2}, m_{v2}$, and integrate each term to recover the original $\vec{m}(u,v)$. I suspect that the extra equation I need in this case might be the first Gauss-Codazzi equation (relating the entries of $\mathbf{a}$ to $K$).

Thanks!

Comment: A plane and a cylinder have identical first fundamental forms if you parametrize them right. You'll never recover a surface unless you know the second fundamental form, as well. And then, you'll only recover it up to rigid motion.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The second fundamental form is identically 0, and I only want to recover the surface up to rigid motion as you state. I've edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Is the question essentially, "Suppose two surface coordinate systems each have first fundamental form components $E$, $F$, and $G$. Are the coordinate systems the same/do they differ by a Euclidean parametrization/some characterizable family of diffeomorphisms?"...?

Comment: I think in simplest terms, I'm asking if the surface coordinate system can be recovered from the fundamental forms together?

Answer (score 1):

If the second fundamental form is identically $0$, then it's a one-line proof that (assuming the surface is connected) the surface is a subset of a plane. You cannot tell which plane — as I said before, any rigid motion preserves first and second fundamental forms.

Comment: But can you reconstruct the surface boundary or is that impossible?

Comment: Your question did not ask about surfaces with boundary; that would make it into a much thornier issue.

Comment: I've edited the question again - thanks for the note. I'm particularly interested in Cartesian square to disk homeomorphisms; several of these exist and I'm wondering if the fundamental forms can be used to determine which homeomorphism was chosen.

Comment: There's no differential geometry whatsoever in this question. You're asking about a mapping from an (open connected) subset of the plane to an (open connected) subset of the plane. And you'd better be talking about *diffeomorphisms*, not homeomorphisms.